# How do I make the Effort column for Features and Epics reflect the total of child stories?

Tags: tfs-2015

As shown in the picture below (Backlog view of the Epics category), currently the effort involved for all the stories contained with a given feature are listed.  The total effort of all of these stories is 31.5.  How can I make TFS reflect this total in the effort column next to the parent feature?

Same question for all features includes as child of an epic?

[image]

Comment: What's detail mean of `in the effort column next to the parent feature` in your question? Did you just want to get the total effort for some stories?

Comment: I tried to fix the image but ran into some technical snag, sorry about that.  Somebody with more patience and enough rep might want to embed the image properly.

Comment: Thanks for the inline image.  In the example I posted, User Stories are child to the Feature.  The Feature has nothing in the Effort column and I wish there was a way to make the child stories total up and be reflected next to Feature.  Same for all Features that are part of the same Epic.

From an answer below, sounds like there is no way to do this currently.

Answer (score 0):

To get the  total effort directly in TFS web portal, there is no this build in option.

If you want to analysis the effort column, you could export the work items to excel: [Bulk add or modify work items with Excel](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel)

---

**Update**

Add a related UserVoice, you can vote up for it and TFS Admin will kindly review it.

> **Make TFS reflect total in the effort column**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/17413633-make-tfs-reflect-total-in-the-effort-column

Comment: Thanks.  I hadn't seen anything, good to know I wasn't crazy :) It isn't a huge thing, just a small thing that would have been nice.  Good to know about the export method tho.